# Adding minutes to timestamp to get an end date and time in java

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, time

So i have a startDate in my java class that gets set as the current time, i also have minutes variable which is the length of time i would like to add onto the startDate in order to create an endDate.

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endTime;

private int minutes;

public void setEndDate{

}
```

I have a getTime method which is used to set the startTime:

```
    Date getTime() {
        Timestamp time = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        return time;
    }
```

How would i go about creating a method to set the end date based on the startDate with minutes added on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `Date` are u using? pls show us the import

Comment: @HazardAGuess If you are using java Date, So you can try `startTime.add(Calendar.MINUTES, minutes);`

Comment: @Jérôme updated question

Comment: @HazardAGuess Can you please show us your imports?

Comment: Is that `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? It makes a difference.